# Testing presence and non-emptyness of dict element

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Given a dictionary dict, is there a more elegant way to do this test?

```
if 'key' in dict and dict['key']:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
if dict.get('key'):
```

If the key is not found, the method will return `None` (which evaluates to `False`).  Otherwise, it will return the value associated with the key.

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> dct = {'a':0, 'b':1}
>>>
>>> dct.get('a')
0
>>> dct.get('b')
1
>>> dct.get('c')  # Returns None with non-existent keys
>>>
>>> bool(dct.get('a'))  # 0 evaluates to False
False
>>> bool(dct.get('b'))  # 1 evaluates to True
True
>>> bool(dct.get('c'))  # The None returned by dict.get evaluates to False
False
>>>
```

Note that you can also specify a default return value:

```
>>> dct.get('c', 'not found')
'not found'
>>>
```

Comment: So to test presence and non-emptyness this way, you'd have to use "if dict.get('key') is not None:"?

Comment: @Laizer - If the key is not found, `dict.get` will return `None`, which the if-statement will then evaluate as `False`.  If the key is found, `dict.get` will return the value associated with it, which the if-statement will then evaluate.  If the value is falsey (`False`, `None`, `0`, empty, etc.), the if-statement will evaluate it as `False`.  Otherwise, it will evaluate it as `True`.  So, the code I posted is just a shorter way of doing what you have already.